# How to resume after a system crash (panic) in OpenBSD?

Tags: openbsd

A crash of some `acpi` process causes OpenBSD to enter `ddb`.

Is it possible to exit `ddb` and keep the system running after that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, if the system has dropped to `ddb` then the kernel has just crashed, there is no recovery from that.  See the `man` page for `crash`[1] for instructions on how to proceed if you want to analyze things further.

You can just issue `boot reboot` at the `ddb` prompt, and reboot the system, but at the very least you should take note of the panic message, to see what triggered it. In your case `acpi` seems to be involved, so you might want/need to disable some devices on the kernel.

[1] [man.openbsd.org](https://man.openbsd.org) is down for maintenance, at the moment, so I can't provide a link, right now.

Comment: To add to this excellent answer, one can also adjust `sysctl.conf` to set `ddb.panic` to `0` if you don't want `ddb` to appear after a crash. In most cases you want `ddb`, but for a remote/inaccessible system (maybe a field system), you might want to disable it to allow the system to attempt to come back online.